# Trying to sync Jenkins workspace to last Perforce label

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, perforce, jenkins-plugins

I currently have a job that creates a label post-build if the build is successful. I am trying to figure out how to sync my workspace to that previous label when the next build is started. On the Configure page, I saw the P4 Label option under the Advanced tab that allows syncing the workspace to a label; I'm trying to figure out how I can use a parameter with this option so it syncs to the most recent label.

I currently use the ${BUILD_NUMBER} variable in my label name when it is created. Is there a way to set a variable equal to the Build Number of the most recently created label?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the capabilities of jenkins, but you can get the most recent label using the following:

```
p4 labels -t ./... | sed 's|^Label\s\+\(\S\+\)\s+\(\S\+\s\+\S\+\)|\2 \1|' | sort | tail -1
```

Notice that the `p4 label` command can also accept a regex to filter only labels that match a given pattern.